# Managing numbers in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a large column, corresponding to variable x which looks like this:

```
198755
-235435436
4353455
-57863489
-2342345
45565768
9865385
-6534
```

etc.

I want to replace this column with the following:

```
1.98755
-2.35435436
4.353455
-5.7863489
-2.342345
4.5565768
9.865385
-6.534
```

That is, I have numbers of various length and sign and I want to put a dot separator after the first figure. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to combine string and numerical manipulations

```
. gen mystr = string(mynum, "%16.0f")
. gen double newnum = real(substr(mystr,1,1) + "." + substr(mystr,2,.)) if mynum >= 0
. replace newnum = -real(substr(mystr,2,1) + "." + substr(mystr,3,.)) if mynum < 0
```

Here `%16.0f` is what looks from your example to be a large enough format so that your numbers aren't mangled. It sounds as if you do not have decimal points in your data.

So the idea is just to insert a decimal point after the first numeric character, which is the second character when the first character is a minus sign.